# onAuthStateChanged is invoked twice while the function in which it resides is called only once

Tags: firebase, firebase-authentication

```
function signInWithGoogle(){
//console.log("clicked signInWithGoogle");
firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged(function(user){
    if(user){
        alert("Already logged in");
    }
    else{
        // var info=document.getElementById("info");
        var provider=new firebase.auth.GoogleAuthProvider();
        firebase.auth().signInWithPopup(provider).then(function(result){
            if(result.credential){
                var token=result.credential.accessToken;

                console.log("token="+token);
            }
            var user=result.user;
            console.log("user_provider="+user.displayName+" user_email="+user.email+" user_dp="+user.photoURL+" user_verification="+user.emailVerified+" uid="+user.uid);
        }).catch(function(error){
            var errorCode=error.code;
            var errorMessage=error.message;
            var email=error.email;
            var credential=error.credential;
            alert(errorMessage);
        });
    }
});
}
```

When a user signs in for the first time, the sign-in process goes well but after that an alert message("Already logged in") is shown, that indicates onAuthStateChanged is called once again.How to make it not call again?

I am sure that that signInWithGoogle() is invoked once.

P.S.  I have seen many questions related to this but they don't have any concrete solution.

Comment: First thing, you shouldn't put `onAuthStateChanged` within `signInWithGoogle`.

Comment: signInWithGoogle is just a function name, the function is called only when user clicks a button.Even if I replaced with some other, the problem still persists.

Comment: I'm just saying that `onAuthStateChanged` shouldn't be inside any function. If `signInWithGoogle` (or any other function) signs the user in `onAuthStateChanged` will get called.

Comment: but why onAuthStateChanged is calling twice, if I clicked on signInWithGoogle once?

Answer (score -1):

`onAuthStateChanged` is called first time when the user is not signed in, you `signInWithPopup`. This causes the user to sign in, triggering this same observer again and hence the alert message.
I agree with @camden_kid's assessment. But if you insist on adding this observer in a sign in function, you can unsubscribe when it is first called:

```
var unsubscribe = firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged(function(user){
  unsubscribe();
  ...
});
```

This would guarantee it is called once each time you call this function.